# ASP.NET MVC multi-level areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I was wondering if creating an area in another area is possible. Have you done it? Or it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

However, as an alternative to areas, you could go with [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting), which allows multiple levels of controllers and automatically structures the routes accordingly.

> Full Disclosure: I am not involved with the MvcCodeRouting project, nor have I used it personally.